# PowerShell session not running more than 100 processes in remote machine

Tags: windows, powershell, taskscheduler

I have an application on a remote machine which spawns about 300 instances of different executable. It works fine when I double click on it, but when I try to execute the main application from a remote machine using PowerShell it does not spawn over 100 instances. One major difference is that when I execute the application through PowerShell it runs as a background process. Below is the command used.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Location 'C:\LatestCode' 
    & Start-Process -FilePath C:\LatestCode\ImageManager-Service.exe -Wait
}
```

It's the same behaviour when I try yo run the application using the Task Scheduler.

Comment: :o surely there's a better way to engineer this...

Comment: I know I am just trying to throttle the machine for max throughput

Comment: Throttle it in the sense of having your hands around its throat, suffocating it? :) :)

Comment: i have a 64 core so not really

Comment: Well, unless you have other problems (Io comes to my mind)... yes, 100 processes on a modern machine with 64 cores is actually not high. Agree,

Comment: Everything works fine when I am logged into the machine I can run 400 instances no problems it's only when I try to do through remote PowerShell it just stops at 100 instance

Comment: Any reason you're using call operator `&` as well as `Start-Process`? Normally you would use one or the other... `& C:\folder\app.exe` or  `Start-Process C:\folder\app.exe` The latter only really needs to be used if you require `-Wait` to wait for execution of next code.

Comment: no reason i have only using start process now,